# PowerBI: The base version should not be negative when the impact is required for a transaction

Tags: powerbi

I'm getting `The base version should not be negative when the impact is required for a transaction"` error when trying to add another table to my PowerBI project.

What the error actually means? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the StackTrace:

```
CommitTransaction

{"changes":[{"relationshipCreate":{"isActive":true,"referentialIntegrity":false,"fromCardinality":"Many","toCardinality":"One","crossFilteringBehavior":"OneDirection","securityFilteringBehavior":0,"fromTableName":"table1","toTableName":"table2" ,"fromColumnName":"store_id","toColumnName":"store_id"}}],"hasQueryImpact":true}

   в System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   в System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   в Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.AsyncModelAuthoringService.RunExtendedModelChangeAsync(Action`1 extendedModelChange, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean blockUI)
   в Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.RunExtendedModelChangeAsync(Action`1 action)
   в Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.PerformLoadInternal(Action relationshipAutodetectStartCallback, ModelChange modelChangeToExecuteBeforeSchemaSync, Boolean skipImpactAnalysisWarning)
   в Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Modeling.PowerQueryToModelLoader.<>c_DisplayClass2.<PerformLoadAsync>b_0()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteEntry(Boolean bPreventDoubleExecution)
   в System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the answer here :

https://forum.enterprisedna.co/t/error-message-base-version-must-not-be-negative/1639/6

In option, I unchecked the "Autodetect new relationships after data is loaded" option in the "Data load" tab and it worked !